# Como usar id únicos globais mais curtos possíveis em URLs?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem

Preciso criar ids em banco de dados que possam ser colocados em URLs, mas queria algo mais curto que uma sequência numérica, que pudesse ser gerado de locais diferentes. Que opções eu tenho?

Comment: você aceitaria uma resposta que gere id unicos globais via uma linguagem de programação? Minha solução seria em Python, e utiliza a lib secrets (mas a implementação concreta também usa base64). Ví que possui a tag banco de dados, não entendi.

Comment: Talvez. A questão talvez seja mais do algoritmo. O problema pode ser da dependência, o que pode ser complicado fazer um *port* para outra linguagem se necessário, mas ruim não é.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem muita solução para isto já que URLs aceitam poucos caracteres, não muito mais que 64 deles, então o que mais se costuma fazer é transformar uma sequência numérica em [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), assim podendo usar letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, além de mais 2 caracteres especiais, pode-se representar números grandes com menos caracteres. Se tem 1 bilhão de combinações pode ter 5 caracteres em vez de 9.

Aí tem a questão da distribuição. Isso é relativamente simples de fazer. Você reserva certas sequências numéricas para certos servidores e dá autonomia para elas usarem, então eles vão controlando a sequência que eles estão, até consumir toda faixa que eles pegaram, daí deve pedir uma nova faixa para um servidor central que controla quem é dono de cada faixa. Por exemplo pode entregar 1 milhão de números em cada faixa, e o servidor vai do começo ao fim dessa faixa e converte para Base64. Isso pode dar uma ligeira dificuldade de otimização em certos SGDBs, mas funciona perfeitamente, a não ser que tenha algum requisito sobre como as sequências devem ser.

Qualquer linguagem deve possuir uma função pronta para converter um número em Base64. Se não tiver precisa construir uma, por exemplo em C [retirado de um Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Miscellaneous/Base64#C):

```c
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>

int base64encode(const void* data_buf, size_t dataLength, char* result, size_t resultSize) {
    const char base64chars[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789~_";
    const uint8_t *data = (const uint8_t *)data_buf;
    size_t resultIndex = 0;
    int padCount = dataLength % 3;
    for (size_t x = 0; x < dataLength; x += 3) {
       uint32_t n = ((uint32_t)data[x]) << 16;
       if ((x + 1) < dataLength) n += ((uint32_t)data[x+1]) << 8;
       if ((x + 2) < dataLength) n += data[x+2];
       uint8_t n0 = (uint8_t)(n >> 18) & 63;
       uint8_t n1 = (uint8_t)(n >> 12) & 63;
       uint8_t n2 = (uint8_t)(n >> 6) & 63;
       uint8_t n3 = (uint8_t)n & 63;
       if (resultIndex >= resultSize) return 1;
       result[resultIndex++] = base64chars[n0];
       if (resultIndex >= resultSize) return 1;
       result[resultIndex++] = base64chars[n1];
       if ((x+1) < dataLength) {
           if (resultIndex >= resultSize) return 1;
           result[resultIndex++] = base64chars[n2];
       }
       if ((x+2) < dataLength) {
           if(resultIndex >= resultSize) return 1;
           result[resultIndex++] = base64chars[n3];
       }
    }
    if (padCount > 0) { 
        for (; padCount < 3; padCount++) { 
            if(resultIndex >= resultSize) return 1;
            result[resultIndex++] = '=';
        } 
    }
    if (resultIndex >= resultSize) return 1;
    result[resultIndex] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/UniqueGlobalId.c).

Note que eu mudei os caracteres extras usados para ficar seguro na URL. Se usar uma função pronta, se não tiver como configurar terá que fazer uma transformação no resultado, já que o normal é usar `+` e `/` que URL não aceita como caractere normal em algumas situações.

Algumas pessoas preferem [Base36](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base36) que não tem que se preocupar com caracteres especiais ou dificuldade para falar ou até escrever por considerar o *case* das letras, mas te ma desvantagem de ficar bem mais longo, o que faz algumas pessoas considerarem que é melhor deixar só numérico mesmo.